# Rcpp function takes a long time to compile

Tags: r, shiny, rcpp

I wrote my first `Rcpp` function and am sourcing it with `sourceCpp`. It takes a long time, but not always (sometimes a couple seconds, but this is the typical):

```
system.time(sourceCpp('04_Rcpp_loads.cpp'))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.02   77.95
```

It processes a large dataframe very quickly, it's just slow to compile.

Here is my `Rcpp` function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector loads(NumericVector feet, double m1, double base_ft, double base_press, double SF) {
    int n = feet.size();
    double calc_0 = 0;
    double calc_1 = 0;
    double calc_2 = 0;
    double calc_3 = 0;
    double calc_4 = 0;
    double calc_5 = 0;
    double calc_6 = 0;
    double calc_7 = 0;
    NumericVector load_psf(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        calc_0 = pow(2 * feet[i] / base_ft, 2.0);
        calc_1 = pow((pow(m1, 2.0) + calc_0) * (calc_0 + 1), 0.5);
        calc_2 = pow(m1, 2.0) + calc_0;
        calc_3 = 1 + calc_0;
        calc_4 = pow(m1, 2.0) + 2 * calc_0 + 1;
        calc_5 = (-2) * m1 * feet[i] / base_ft;
        calc_6 = pow(m1, 2.0) + calc_0 + 1;
        calc_7 = asin(m1 / calc_1);
        load_psf[i] = 2 * base_press * SF *((calc_5 / pow(calc_6, 0.5)) * calc_4 / (calc_3 * calc_2) + calc_7) / 3.14159265;
    }
    return load_psf;   
}
```

The function is used in an app on `shinyapps.io`. I don't know what is happening there, but it takes a long time to start up the app, so I suspect the same thing. The output above is directly from RStudio on my Windows machine. All packages updated to latest version as of this posting.

I suspect there is a way I can make this faster - by pre-compiling it perhaps? How do I make this faster? And when I do, how will I run it on `shinyapps.io`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of quick points:

1. If you make your function part of a package, it is compiled once 'off-line' and you can just load it, which is essentially "free" in terms of resourse use.. That is what I would do.
2. There are compilation options as you can now choose between headers `Rcpp/Rcpp`, `Rcpp/Light`, `Rcpp/Lighter` and `Rcpp/Lightest` (which choose how many optional `Rcpp` features are included.
3. Compilation is known to be expensive. Where possible, I always try to rely on cached compilation via `ccache` -- see [this blog post of mine for more](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2017/11/27/).

Hope this helps. Happy to discuss more, maybe on the rcpp-devel list.

Comment: in addition to 1, to make a custom package run on shiny apps you can use `remotes::install_github("myRepo/myPackage")` to install it locally, then `rsconnect::deployApp()` will know to get your package from github and install it for you on shinyapps. So I agree, option 1 is the best for this use-case

Comment: @tospig  (1) Do I need to use RStudio's `Build Binary`? (2) If I have it compiled locally from running `remotes::install_github(.)` , then how does my Shinyapps.io script know to get it from github? Or do I use `remotes::install_github(.)` in the script? Wouldn't the app compile it each time it is run then?

Comment: You are confused between a _source package_ (on your GitHub repo) and _binary package_ the shinyapps.io server could install.  You can still create and prepare _binary_ packages from source packages -- RHub can help -- and serve those from GH for use in deployments elsewhere (and my [drat](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=drat) package can help).  You could also rely on [r-universe](https://r-universe.dev).  If all this is word salad to you (it's a lot of material at once) consider befriending a nearby sys admin.

Comment: 2) - yes - and shinyapps **just knows** to install it from the same location. When you deploy a shiny app to `shinyapps`, `rsconnect` knows how and from where you installed each of your packages. lt then tells `shinyapps` to also install it from these same locations (if it can). Official docs - https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud

Comment: and you don't need (and shouldnt use) any `install()` commands in your script.

Comment: Thanks. I've created the package, and used `remotes::install_github()` to install locally. The shinyapp won't run locally, it can't find my Rcpp function. Do I need to have a separate `sourceCpp()` script in my package that compiles the Rcpp function?

Comment: Please take a look at what `Rcpp.package.skeleton("mytestpkg")` creates and adapt it to your function.  If you can install and run _locally_ from `mytestpkg`, then shinyapps.io will too.

Comment: I think my problem is deeper. I can't use R past version 4.1.3 because rtools isn't installed correctly, or I don't have my environmental variables set up correctly. I've been battling this for months. Now, compiling my Rcpp package I'm getting `line 1: C:/rtools40;/mingw32/bin/g++: No such file or directory`  There's a semicolon after `rtools40` in that path

Comment: Secret weapon:  Use win-builder, or r-hub (apparently temporarily down) to build a package for you.  Combine with, say, the few free hours at rstudio.cloud to work on the package on a known-working setup.

Comment: If you have set up your package correctly, and written the cpp function correctly, there won't be any need for `sourceCpp()`.